# How to Clean Sensitive Data from SQL Server Dump Files

Tags: sql-server, security, ssms, sqldump

**How do I clean a SQL Server dump file of confidential/PII/PHI information so I can prepare it for third party analysis?** What am I looking for in the dump files and are there any automated tools to obfuscate things? I have looked on Microsoft and other sites but the information is focused on how to diagnose SQL dumps rather than what is actually contained within.

In the most recent release of SSMS they have the "SQL Server Diagnostics (Preview)" (https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sql_server_team/sql-server-diagnostics-preview/) which offers to "Analyze Dumps - Customers using this extension will be able to debug and self-resolve memory dump issues".

I'd like to utilize this new tool but confidentiality is paramount, hence the question.

Comment: You won't be able to strip information from those dumps. Do not use that functionality if you have confidential data.

Comment: These files are minidump files such as SQLDump0001.mdmp

Comment: Or more precisely, you *shouldn't* strip any information from those dumps. If you work with someone to analyze this data (whether Microsoft or a consultant), make sure you have appropriate data confidentiality agreements in place.

Comment: It looks like this is not an option for me, thank you for the information.